# Is there a Copy-and-Paste List of Popular Math Formulas?

Tags: math-mode

I prepare lessons for my students in printed form as well as on a Wordpress blog. All my prep is done in a simple text editor in Markdown, and I have generally avoided putting in math formulas and instead just relied on the dry erase marker in class, or directing the students to a certain formula sheet that comes with their books. I get by, but a colleague of mine recently tipped me off to LaTex/Tex when I was telling him about Markdown.

I've been able to install MathJax in wordpress, and I have a Multimarkdown preview app (Marked) that also connects to MathJax, so I've been able to get a couple of test posts up.

I'd love to just have a plain text file that I could copy and paste from that has popular formulas for an intro stats class (standard deviation, confidence interval, mean, etc.). I'd also just love a bunch of practice problems I could copy the original LaTeX code and paste right into my text editor.

I guess I'm looking for a math textbook in its original LaTeX code, or a resource for math teachers designed for copy and pasting.

Does such a resource exist?

Comment: For using LaTeX with WordPress you might be interested in [QuickLaTeX](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Math equations in Wikipedia articles are written in LaTeX. Wikipedia is easy to search and likely has all of the equations for an intro stats class.

For example, if you want the equation for sample standard deviation you could navigate to the relevant Wikipedia article ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)), go down to the section that has the relevant equation, then click on "[edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Standard_deviation&action=edit&section=7)" to see the LaTeX code for the equation. For this example, the equation for sample standard deviation is given as `s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \overline{x})^2}`.

With all of these steps, it would probably be faster to just write the LaTeX equations by hand; this depends of course on the specific equation.

Comment: you don't need to "edit" to access the wikipedia TeX code, just rigth-click (or equivalent) in the equation image and look for "image info" (or equivalent) and you can access the field "associated text" which is the raw TeX code that you can copy.

Answer (score 8):

- Try http://www.equationsheet.com/, it is not exhaustive but it has some search capability.
- NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions http://dlmf.nist.gov/ has all its mathematical formulas and identities encoded in TeX form which can downloaded and copied.

Answer (score 6):

[Web equation](http://webdemo.myscript.com/views/math.html) is a good resource for math teachers designed for copy and pasting. Click on the garbage can to clear the screen and then write your formula/equation; the formula gets built in the bottom left hand corner. You can also undo/redo mistakes with the arrows at the top lefthand corner. When the formula is correct, highlight the LaTeX code in the bottom righthand corner and copy/paste into your document. Since equations are in math mode, you will need to paste in between $ signs.

Comment: It seems to have moved. Try [here](http://webdemo.myscript.com/views/math.html). The LaTeX formula is now in the upper right and they've added a graph for some simple functions.

Answer (score 5):

Springer offers a very nice utility to search for equations at  http://latexsearch.com/

You can search for code snippets or for topics.