# Is there a Copy-and-Paste List of Popular Statistical Formulas in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Copy-and-Paste List of Popular Math Formulas?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51044/is-there-a-copy-and-paste-list-of-popular-math-formulas)

I am just discovering LaTeX as a way of making worksheets and blog posts for my math classes. I already have my Wordpress installation setup to use MathJax. I would need to make the same formulas over and over again, so it would make sense if there was a plain text file somewhere where someone had written out popular math formulas (standard deviation, area of a circle, z-test, etc) that I could just copy and paste into my class notes.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what Math classes you teach? Statistics, Calculus, Linear Algebra?

Comment: Intro and inferential stats, number theory, algebra, geometry and precalc

Comment: Perhaps you could find a maths books whose Latex source is online?

Comment: I flagged a moderator attention to migrate to TeX.SE.