# library of latex formulas

Tags: physics

I want to write a lot of famous formulas, but they are big and they take time. Is there a place, where I can type the name of a formula, for example, "Maxwell equations" and get in a couple of seconds the latex code?

Comment: Very closely related (but math instead of physics): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51044/is-there-a-copy-and-paste-list-of-popular-math-formulas

Comment: @Marijn yes, thank you, it is a good solution to take formulas from "edit" in Wikipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) is a tool that you can take a "screenshot" and converts the equation inside the image to a latex formula. So look at any Wikipedia page or other sources with the equations and just "copy" them from there.